# Iterate through a pandas dataframe column and eval with an if statement and pass the column values to an empty list/dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

new to python and pandas,i have a dataframe with headers :

**sl.no  ObjectPartCode  TRAINSET  Fault_code  Date  Month  Year   Fdate**

The values of TRAINSET have been sorted,
i want to iterate over the column TRAINSET and if **successive** 'TRAINSET' values are same , I want to append TRAINSET values and corresponding FDATE values to a dictionary/list. 
**This is what i've tried:**

```
for i,column in df['TRAINSET'].iteritems():

     # Select column contents by column name using [] operator
 columnSeriesObj = df['TRAINSET']
 if ['TRAINSET'](i)==['TRAINSET'](i-1):
     list1.append(columnSeriesObj(i))
```

**but the error comes up :**

```
if ['TRAINSET'](i)==['TRAINSET'](i-1):
```

**TypeError: 'list' object is not callable**

i know i am doing something terribly wrong while indexing the values in the column, please let me know..

Comment: it is not really clear what you are trying to do. please provide a sample input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `['TRAINSET']` by using index like you are doing.

By writing `['TRAINSET']` you are just creating a list having `'TRAINSET'` string as an element in it.

Also looks like you are trying to access a list by index with `paranthesis ()` which is not correct.

Most probably you are trying to do :

```
columnSeriesObj = df['TRAINSET'].tolist()
list1 = []
for i in range(len(columnSeriesObj)):
    if columnSeriesObj[i] == columnSeriesObj[i-1] and columnSeriesObj[i] not in list1:
        list1.append(columnSeriesObj[i])
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so soon. are you converting the specific column into a list  to iterate through it?     
 the solution gives the following error **list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: sorry for being such a noob , the solution has an error though

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Typo was while iterating i did not iterate over the `indexes`. I iterated over `elements` and that's why it showed this error. Edited answer.  And yes I converted the column values into list.